# ios - getting exception after deleting a button reference

Tags: ios, ios5

I previously made a button and from the storyboard, dragged it to the .h file, and set it like this:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *deleteComment;
```

then I realized I needed an action button and erased the code for this button. Now when I try to go to this screen, I get this exception:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<TopicEditController 0xa027ac0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key edit.'
*** First throw call stack:
```

and the system points to this spot:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool 
    {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

Could someone please advise me how to stop this from happening?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you also delete the previous connection (the one to the outlet) inside your xib/storyboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your button still is linked to the outlet you deleted. Go into Interface Builder an selet your button. Open the inspector on the right side and delete the outlet connection.

[image]